# I cant see reskins in new update in Team Fortress 2

Tags: team-fortress-2, directx-9

I can't see the new reskins in the new update. it says that DirectX
 8.0 is the reason. But how to I update DirectX to 9.0?

Answer (score 3):

Use the launch option -dxlevel90 to launch in DirectX 9 (in Steam, right click TF2 > properties > set launch options)

If that doesn't work, check your autoexec.cfg file in your cfg folder (`Steam\SteamApps\Common\Team Fortress 2\tf\cfg`) and see if there's a command forcing you into DirectX 8, such as `mat_dxlevel`